# Will deleting main partition delete the partition that was created by shrinking the main partition?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, partitioning

[Partition details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMR6j.png)

My partition details is given in pic above.
The **partition 4** was created by shrinking the available space in **partition 3** that contained windows os.

Now, I am going to delete **partition 3**, will that delete my **partition 4** or its data??

if not, then what happens to **partition 4** and its data?
I need the data of **partition 4**, its very important, and its very heavy in size, can take many days to backup. I want to delete the windows os in **partition 3** without deleting the **important data** in **partition 4**.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting 3 will not magically delete 4.

What will happen is that after 3 is removed the partition-numbering will change. (4 will be become 3, etc.)

If your fstab uses GUID numbers to mount partitions everything will keep working because GUID numbers are independent of the partition numbers.

But if your fstab uses devices names (that are derivates of the partition numbers) any partition that got a different number is not longer automatically mounted (OR mounted on the wrong mount-point). You may have to manually adjust the fstab entries to compensate for that.

Anyway, you won't loose any data.